# Computer Networks, OSI model

Tags: computer-architecture, shortest-path

1. What layer of OSI model does define the route of information transmission between sender and receiver computers?

A) Session layer
B) Physical layer
C) Data link layer
D) Network layer
E) Transport layer

In this question I think answer must be Network layer.But my teacher insists that answer is Transport layer.Even though i have shown in so many books it was written like that:

"Path Determination. The network layer must determine the route or path taken by packets as they flow from a
sender to a receiver. The algorithms that calculate these paths are referred to as routing algorithms."

this is from book that name is "Computer Networking: Top-Down approach, 5th edition,James Kurose",

chapter 4.1.Introduction and Network Service Models

Comment: This is a better question for serverfault or superuser

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft [sf] is for questions about professional network management; this question is certainly off-topic, there. It also doesn't look on-topic at [su], which is about solving practical problems with computer systems, not about discussing theoretical models of network architectures.

Answer (score 1):

The Transport layer offers services as:

- Connection-oriented communication
- Same order delivery
- Reliability
- Flow control
- Congestion avoidance
- Multiplexing

The network layer is responsible for packet forwarding including routing through intermediate routers.

The answer is definitely Network layer.